# Cannot properly set RequestOptionsArgs of POST, in service

Tags: angular, angular6

I use angular 6 and I was following along [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y) to submit images.

I would like to observe the progress of the form submission, so I can get the percentage of the uploaded file.

I have this in my component

```
import { HttpClient,HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    private myService:MyService,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private carouselConfig : NgbCarouselConfig    ,
    private http:HttpClient
   ) { }

    let headers = new Headers();    
    headers.append('Authorization',this.token);    
    let eb =null;
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload',formData,{reportProgress:true,observe:'events'}).subscribe(
      event=>{        
        if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
          let pv = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total *100);
          this.imguploadprogress.nativeElement.value =  pv;          
        }
        else if(event.type === HttpEventType.Response){     
          eb = event.body;              
          if(eb.success){                  
            this.imguploadprogress.nativeElement.value =  100;                                   
            this.imageMsg='All good';                                       
          }
          else{
            this.imguploadprogress.nativeElement.value =  0;
            this.imageMsg='nope;        
          }
        }        
    });
```

This works fine.

I try to "split" this now in two parts. Turn the post and its headers and its parameters to a function in my service, and just subscribe and get the results in the component. I try to do this:

`myapp.component.ts`

```
this.myService.uploadImage(form).subscribe(
  e=>{
    console.log('e- ',e);
  }
);
```

and in my service 
`myapp.service.ts`

```
  uploadImage(data) {
    let formData = new FormData(data);
    let headers = new Headers();    
    headers.append('Authorization',this.token);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload',formData,{reportProgress:true, observe:'events', headers:headers});
  }
```

VScode says `Argument of type {reportProgress:boolean;observe:string;headers:Headers} is not assingable to parameter of type RequestOptionsArgs`

During compile I get `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reportProgress' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.` and when I try to use the form I get just the final response object back, with no event info in between.

So, how can I properly set my RequestOptionsArgs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing APIs, `reportProgress` is a property of `HttpRequest<T>` which lives in `@angular/common/http`.

In your example, it seems you are basing your service in the Angular 6 `Http` injectable service from the `HttpModule` in `@angular/http`.

- Instead, use the `request` method from `HttpClient` that comes in `@angular/common/http`.
- Also, make sure you use `HttpHeaders` from `@angular/common/http` as well.

The following will work:

```
uploadImage(data) {
  let formData = new FormData(data);
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.token);
  return this.httpClient.post(
    'http://localhost:3000/cms/upload',
    formData,
    {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
      headers: headers
    });
}
```

Of course you will have to import:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And inject the `HttpClient` in your service constructor:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { ... }
```

I hope this explains and resolves your issue!

Comment: Since `HttpHeaders` is ummutable, it needs to be `let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.token);`

Comment: Hi Fernando. Thanks for the tips, it worked. I need your help in one last thing. The event I get in the front-end (`myService.uploadImage(form).subscribe`) does not have a `HttpEventType` anymore, to check the progress and the final response. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: For now I do  `this.myService.uploadImage(form).subscribe(
  e=>{
    console.log('e- ',e);
  }
);` and I can see only some `{type: 1, loaded: 173047, total: 173047}` as the event. I need at least some `UploadProgress` to update a progress bar. In my first example when it was all in the component, I was using `HttpClient` from `'@angular/common/http'` but `Headers` from `'@angular/http'` and I could do this `if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)` and this else if(event.type === HttpEventType.Response)`. Check my original post for more. Thanks

Comment: hi @slevin - I checked and I can confirm that when you do `myService.uploadImage(form).subscribe(e => { ... })` the value of `e.type` is actually of enum type `HttpEventType`, and you should be able to match it against `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` or `HttpEventType.DownloadProgress`, etc. I pushed an example on GitHub for you using `switch (event.type)` block: https://github.com/fernandoespinosa/ng-request-options-args/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L27 - Let me know if that clarifies usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your third argument to http.post is the httpOptions, yours looks like

```
{reportProgress:true, observe:'events', headers:headers}
```

According to the good ol' 
https://angular.io/guide/http

it is shown an example where they use:

```
{ observe: 'response' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `http.request('post',...`

Instead of `http.post(...`

To make a request with progress events enabled, you can create an instance of **HttpRequest** with the **reportProgress** option set true to enable tracking of progress events.

```js
uploadImage(data) {
  let formData = new FormData(data);
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Authorization', "mytoken");


  return this.http.request('post', 'http://localhost:3000/cms/upload', {
    body: formData,
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events',
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'json'
  });
}
```

This follow the documentation https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Answer (score 1):

**In your case**,

- `reportProgress` property is associated with `HttpRequest<T>` class from `@angular/common/http`.
  See the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest).
- `headers` property is associated with `Headers` class from `@angular/http` which is **DEPRECATED** now. See the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers).
- The reason for your issue is **Types of property `headers` are incompatible**.

**Solution**,

- `headers` property should be associated with `HttpRequest<T>`  class from `@angular/common/http` instead `Headers` class from `@angular/http`.

Change your `myapp.service.ts` class as below,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class MyAppService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    uploadImage(data) {

    let formData = new FormData(data);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
                    .append('Authorization', this.token);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload', formData,
              { reportProgress : true, 
                observe : 'events', 
                headers : headers });
  }

}
```

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate answer from the original one below.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest signature, I think you have to make sure that your headers is an HttpHeaders

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
```

Also make sure you are using:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```